# No consigo añadir datos a un array

Tags: javascript

He creado un array vacio el cual es:

```
let datos = [];
```

A este array tengo que añadirle los números del 1 al 30 con un bucle for, el bucle ya lo tengo hecho pero no consigo añadir los números al array
el bucle lo tengo de la siguiente forma

```
for (var x=1;x<=30;x++){
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Como lo tratabas de realizar?, agrégalo Marina, recuerda agregar esta información, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si te sirve, tú podrías generar un array de números del `1` al `30` con [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (a partir de EcmaScript 6):

```
let datos=Array.from({length: 30}, (x, i) => i+1);
```

Ejemplo:

```js
let datos=Array.from({length: 30}, (x, i) => i+1);
console.log(datos);
```

Y, si los índices debieran empezar con `0`, podrías usar simplemente [`Array.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys). Por ejemplo:

```js
let datos = [...Array(30).keys()];
console.log(datos);
```

Fuente: [Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559488/5587982).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) para insertar datos a tu array, ejemplo:

```js
let datos = [];

for (var x=1;x<=30;x++){
    //Inserta numeros en array.
    datos.push(x);  
}

//Imprime valores del array.
console.log(datos);
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido!

Answer (score 1):

El resultado mas sencillo sería añadir el numero cada vez que la repetitiva actúa una vez. Para añadir solamente usa la función `push()`
Modificando el código quedaría así:

```
let datos = [];
for (var x=1;x<=30;x++){
datos.push(x)
console.log(x);}
```

En este caso lo que estamos haciendo es guardar la X que irá tomando un valor de 1 a 30. Por lo tanto cuando finalice el for tendrás el array con los 30 numeros.